# Google Maps - Street View custom overlay link

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-static-api, google-street-view

Does anyone know if it is possible to add an click event (e.g. a link) to a custom overlay on a google street view?

In the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewOverlays) it shows this [example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-overlays):

If you 'Toggle Street View' You can see the yellow custom markers. So what I'm wondering if it is possible to add a click event to the marker to open a link or even update a separate block of content on the page?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know you do not need to do anything special for street-view to have click events on markers. But if you have a certain overlay that is not shown in the street-view then it can't be clicked.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    console.log('clicked');             
});
```